# Disable wildcard subscriptions in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, messagebroker

Is it possible to disallow topic subscriptions to wildcards in ActiveMQ 5 (classic)?

E.g. subscribing to `>` will broadcast all messages to all consumers even if a consumer should not be able to subscribe to all topics (and isn't even aware of all topics).

I already tried to create `<authorizationEntries>` with the `<authorizationPlugin>`, but wasn't able to prohibit wildcard subscription.

Do you have any ideas how to completely wildcard subscription or message forwarding to wildcards for specific / all users?

Comment: You are thinking about it the wrong way round. Clients can subscribe to what ever they want, what you control is what is actually delivered to them by providing a white list of what they are allowed in the ACL

Comment: @hardillb Yeah I thought about that, but to my knowledge there is no API for dynamically adding new users, so I have to share credentials between up to 500k clients.

Comment: ActiveMQ supports JAAS plugins for user authentication/authorisation so you should be able to easily dynamically add/remove users and ACL entries. https://activemq.apache.org/security p.s. sharing credentials is a REALLY bad idea

Answer (score 0):

As hashed out in the comments you are approaching this problem from the wrong direction. Rather than trying to disable wildcard subscriptions the correct approach is to limit what topics will actually be delivered regardless of what is subscribed to.

This is done by setting an appropriate ACL for each user (reusing the same credentials for 500k clients is a REALLY bad idea).

ActiveMQ uses a plugin based system to supply Authentication and Authorisation control based on the Java standard called JAAS. With JAAS you can plug nearly any storage mechanism (e.g. database, LDAP,...) into ActiveMQ to store your user/password details and the ACL of what topics they can access. Details of how to use JAAS with ActiveMQ can be found [here](https://activemq.apache.org/security)